# R: Any R function can find mapping or matching from one nested list to another (reproducible example is given)?

Tags: r, vector, nested, mapping

Here I have two list where one is nested list with containing two "IntegerList" like object, and second one with list of data.frame objects.I am wondering that any R function can find corresponding mapping from list element from nested list to list of data.frame objects recursively, then I call my own function for them. However, I implemented function that takes two argument where one args is list element from nested list, second one is data.frame objects from df object list.

This is the quick reproducible example with toy data:

```
m <- as(list(c(1:2), 3, 4, integer(0), 6), "CompressedIntegerList")
n <- as(list(1,3,6, integer(0), 8), "CompressedIntegerList")

d <- data.frame(x1=seq(2,5,9), x2=seq(4,5,9), x3=LETTERS[seq(1:8)], score=sample(1:12, 8))
e <- data.frame(x1=seq(1,9,8), x2=seq(7,9,8), x3=letters[seq(1:8)], score=sample(1:10, 8))
df.li <- list(d,e)
nested_list <- list(m,n)
```

for example, 1st list element of nested element is corresponds to 1st data.frame object of list of df.li, so I want have this matches and pass them to my own function recursively. I am seeking if I have several list object in nested_list, so what would be nice version of my function?

I tired nested lapply for them, but when I called my own function, it gave me error. I tested my own function and I am prettry sure that nested_list and df.li correspond by parallel gemotrically (pair-wise). 
so I am looking for any R function that can find such mapping. Is there any R function can do this?

Comment: Welcome! Please consider providing some short example R code to illustrate what you have and where you want to go to. 
Something like the following example question: 
"I have a list. Is there a way to compute the mean of all elements? Example: `a = list(1,2,3,4); something(a) # --> should output 2.5 `". 

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is your expected output with your `nested_list` and `df.li`?

Comment: To be precisely, if you test my reproducible example, in nested_list, some rows has two index, I want to keep it one of them, then expand this by using data.frame objects in df.li. so basically, nested_list is index of df.li, so it is like mapping index to data.frame objects, and expected to be expand them as new list of data.frame objects without duplicated instance after all.

Comment: It's most helpful to keep the example input *and* the example output as explicit as possible -- you provided a concrete minimal example, which is good, it would be equally helpful if you could just specify with R code, which R object you would expect to be produced from that input you have provided. Then anyone can try if she can generate that object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mapply`.

Here is an example which determines if certain values show up in corresponding `data.frame`s

```
# List of data.frames
dfs = list(
  data.frame( name = c("Lorem", "ipsum"),
              id   = c(0, 1)),
  data.frame( name = c("dolor", "sit"),
              id   = c(2,3))
)

# List of ids
ids = c(1,5)

# Function checks whether i occurs in the id column of the data.frame df
id.in.data.frame = function(i, df){
  return( i %in% df$id )
}

# Check whether id 1 occurs in the first data.frame and id 5 occurs in the
# second data.frame
mapply(FUN = id.in.data.frame, 
       i = ids, # use the parameter names of id.in.data.frame ...
       df = dfs  # ... as parameter names here
)
# --> Returns: [1] TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: I have added reproducible example for my problem. Thank you